# Suggestion message not working. Does not seem to find the message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a channel on my discord so that as soon as someone sends a message, it deletes it, then send an embed with the information. But it does not work, it should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my `index.js`:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id !== "823027303129808896") return;
  let content = message.content;
  const delMSG = message;
  
  
  const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
  .setTitle("Nouvelle suggestion!")
  .setDescription("**Suggestion:**\n" + content)
  .setColor("#00ff44")
  .setFooter("Eclezia", "https://i.imgur.com/GhHHBgn.png")
  .setTimestamp();
  message.guild.channels.cache.get("823027303129808896").send(Embed).then((m) => {
    m.react("<:yes:821050283734859816>")
    m.react("<:no:821050300730572802>")
  })
  delMSG.delete();
})
```

And here is the error I get:

```
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\EcleziaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\EcleziaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/channels/823027303129808896/messages/823046250542399539/reactions/yes%3A821050283734859816/@me',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

EDIT: Look at the marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

- Make sure you're returning if the message's author is the bot using `if (message.author.bot) return;` (I think it was your main issue)
- You don't need to create new variables `content` and `delMSG` as `message` is available until your last line of code
- You don't need to get the channel if you're sending in the same channel. Instead of `message.guild.channels.cache.get("823027303129808896")` you can use `message.channel`
- I would move the `message.delete()` inside the `.then()`

Here is the full code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const channelID = '823027303129808896';

  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id !== channelID) return;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTitle('Nouvelle suggestion!')
    .setDescription('**Suggestion:**\n' + message.content)
    .setColor('#00ff44')
    .setFooter('Eclezia', 'https://i.imgur.com/GhHHBgn.png')
    .setTimestamp();

  message.channel
    .send(embed)
    .then((msg) => {
      message.delete();

      msg.react('<:yes:821050283734859816>');
      msg.react('<:no:821050300730572802>');
    })
    .catch(console.log);
});
```

[image]

Comment: I still get the same error, the embed flickers then it looks like https://share.zariaa.tk/s/8GVfXSJwcj.png

Comment: Did you copy-paste the whole code I posted?

Comment: I'm guessing I shouldn't have done that..?

Comment: No, it should work fine by copy pasting. The only time I receive the error is when I remove the `if (message.author.bot)` part.

Comment: I needed to separate the message.author.bot from the channel thing

Comment: Okay, that's strange. I hope it works fine now, I've just updated the answer.